# Eclipse content assist (JavaCompletionProposalComputer) not triggered

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, content-assist

I have a plugin that implements a content assist hook using JavaCompletionProposalComputer. Upon that event, I compute something and the update my view. The problems is that the view stays on and I am not able to trigger content assist and thus my handlers. When I minimize the view, I am able to use it again normally. Is this some kind of focus problem? How to solve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please detail a bit your use-case. It is a bit unclear what happens, where is the view, what it means 'it stays on' (it works the first time?), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that my problem was related to focus. For some reason, the focus was lost whenever I "showed" a view. I resolved the issue by replacing

```
IWorkbenchPage.showView(view_id)
```

with

```
IWorkbenchPage.bringToTop(view)
```

Hope somebody will find this useful.